# Token Firebase IOS não funciona... retorna valor null

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ola pessoal estou com um problema em um aplicativo feito no Xamarin, eu utilizo o Cloud Messaging do Firebase para receber Push, porém na hora do código gerar o Token ele retorna valor null, alguém poderia me ajudar?

ESSA É A PARTE DO AppDelegate

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Firebase.CloudMessaging;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using UserNotifications;
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Firebase.InstanceID;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using KeyboardOverlap.Forms.Plugin.iOSUnified;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;

namespace Teste.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options);
            KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init();

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
            }
            else
            {

                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            // Firebase component initialize                        
            //Firebase.Analytics.App.Configure();
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

            InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
            {
                var newToken = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
                // if you want to send notification per user, use this token
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);

                connectFCM();
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "EnviarToken",
            (sender) =>
            {
                string Token = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;              
                MessagingCenter.Send<Object, string>(this, "PegarToken", Token);
            });

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Disconnect();
        }

        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            connectFCM();
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
#if DEBUG
            InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Sandbox);
#endif
#if RELEASE
            Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Prod);
#endif
        }

        // iOS 9 <=, fire when recieve notification foreground
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

            // Generate custom event
            NSString[] keys = { new NSString("Event_type") };
            NSObject[] values = { new NSString("Recieve_Notification") };
            var parameters = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys, values, keys.Length);

            // Send custom event
            Firebase.Analytics.Analytics.LogEvent("CustomEvent", parameters);

            if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userInfo);
                var aps_d = userInfo["aps"] as NSDictionary;
                var alert_d = aps_d["alert"] as NSDictionary;
                var body = alert_d["body"] as NSString;
                var title = alert_d["title"] as NSString;
                debugAlert(title, body);
            }
        }

        // iOS 10, fire when recieve notification foreground
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            var title = notification.Request.Content.Title;
            var body = notification.Request.Content.Body;
            debugAlert(title, body);
        }

        private void connectFCM()
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect((error) =>
            {
                if (error == null)
                {
                    //TODO: Change Topic to what is required
                    Messaging.SharedInstance.Subscribe("/topics/all");
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error != null ? "error occured" : "connect success");
            });
        }

        private void debugAlert(string title, string message)
        {
            var alert = new UIAlertView(title ?? "Title", message ?? "Message", null, "Cancel", "OK");
            alert.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Error removing keypair status: -34018
Unable to remove RSA keypair
Unable to generate keypair.
Failed to get InstanceID: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá aparentemente o código está correto, tem duas coisas que podem estar com problema os certificados .p12 tente gerar e subir novamente no projeto do firebase ou veja se seu Google-Services.plist está na pasta iOS e se foi foi incluído build action BundleResource para ele.